# Param variable to string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Which is the best way to convert that :id variable 
`@object = Object.find(params[:id])`

into a string?

```
render :json => {"status" => "404", "message" => "Object with id " + ":id" + " not found"}
```

Also tried:

```
render :json => {"status" => "404", "message" => "Object with id #{:id} not found"}
```

But it gives this error:

> no implicit conversion of Symbol into String

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just replace `#{:id}` with `"#{params[:id]}"`

Comment: Precisely. Just use the same notation as in the controller, `params` is available in both controller and view contexts.

Comment: Without the #? It just writes down "params[:id]" but not the actual content of the variable